# AMDGPU-PRO breaks boot (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, gpu-driver, amdgpu

- Ubuntu Desktop version 16.04
- AMDGPU-PRO version 17.10-414273
- GPU: RX 480
- UEFI with secure-boot disabled

On a fresh installation of Ubuntu, I installed AMDGPU-PRO by following [the guide on AMD's site](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx). Commands repeated here in case the link goes dead:

```
apt update
apt dist-upgrade
cd /tmp
tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro-17.10-414273.tar.xz
cd amdgpu-pro-17.10-414273
./amdgpu-pro-install -y
```

After restarting, Ubuntu gets stuck booting indefinitely with the following text displayed in tty7:

```
/dev/sdb5: clean 414434/8847360 files, 8735918/35384576
_
```

At this point, I can switch to a different tty and login, etc.

Logging in and running `amdgpu-pro-uninstall` and restarting fixes the hang on boot...but then I don't have drivers.

It might be important to note that I'm dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu from different partitions on the same disk.

Comment: Your output indicates how far along in the process you got (fsck of /dev/sdb5) but we don't have any errors to work with. Please [edit] any errors in /var/log/syslog from the boot process into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Unfortunately can't answer cuz low rep. AMD driver Linux install guide - http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx . From the broken boot screen hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 to enter cmd. Ensure AMDGPU pro is installed via `dpkg -l amdgpu-pro` and ensure you're on video group `sudo usermod -a -G video $LOGNAME `. Reboot + Reinstall until it shows up. Once its there there uninstall it  `amdgpu-pro-uninstall`.  This will fix boot but leave you to integrated/bad GPU.

Answer (score 0):

I have practically the same setup, dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04.2.  I posted another answer since my issue was during the reboot or shutdown.  i ran the below and everything seems to be working now.

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall

I also ran the command on ATI AMD site to add to video group.  Maybe it will work for you since I got that weirdness after an update and the same AMD driver version.